# Generic way to handle record locking errors in a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, locking

We have locking errors when creating records (e.g. a contact locks on household) or updating records with flows. As this is a common problem I was wondering why there is no generic APEX Action that could be used instead of the update/insert statements. Such an action could use the FOR UPDATE keyword, see [Any Reason NOT to Use FOR UPDATE?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385515/any-reason-not-to-use-for-update)

I don't think there is a proper way to add error handling inside the flow, correct? Or would you add a loop that tries for example 3 times?

Error message:

> This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records: 0013X...

It's pretty surprising that Salesforce does not address this issue generally in all update / create elements. They should add a retry mechanism inside it.

Please note that these updates are not causing any conflicts in data. I'm pretty sure that a modern database or a differently optimized database could handle all those "concurrent" updates to the records.

Comment: Retries do not make sense in many cases. Retrying 3 times could easily result in a 30 second execution time just for that one DML. Flows support fault handlers, allowing you to have the flow perform the logic you need.

Comment: Well it could, I still would want to spend more time than failing. The errors we see are not easy to recover, e.g. origin is a web form request with web-to-lead. Also this is the reason that the supported fault handlers are not of much use. Or how would you use them? Save the payload somewhere on another object or log file?