SOQL "FOR UPDATE" keyword Understanding
Can someone please help me in understanding of the FOR UPDATE keyword in SOQL.
Exactly when should we use this,
what is the need to put an explicit lock on record?
Whenever we do any DML, by default an implicit lock gets placed and until that lock is released nobody else would be able to update that record, and if it takes more than 10 seconds to complete the Update Operation, the parallel transaction would be timed out and will give Exception "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW...".
Does "FOR UPDATE" helps eliminates LOCKING issue??
Is it recommended to use FOR UPDATE in LOCKING issues?

Here you can find nice answers about FOR UPDATE https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385515/any-reason-not-to-use-for-update

As mentioned in Avoiding Deadlocks, Apex does try to avoid deadlocks by locking parents before children, and by record Id order when editing multiple records (e.g. Apex, Data Loader, etc). However, developers should avoid deadlocks by using FOR UPDATE in their application code, taking care to lock records in the same order through their code.
If you use FOR UPDATE in your query, you will guarantee that you are not trying to update a record that is already being modified in another transaction. This is also what provides you with the approximately 10 seconds for the other transaction to finish updating the record. If you don't use this keyword, there are two potential negative effects. First, if you query records that are already locked in another transaction, you will see the record as it was before the other transaction modified the record; you may be operating on stale data. The query won't wait for that other transaction to finish before returning the database result.
Second, if you attempt to perform a DML operation on a record that is already locked, your transaction doesn't get 10 seconds before the operation fails--it'll fail in under a second with the error. Let's walk through both of these scenarios to see what happens.
For the first scenario, let us imagine we have two different units of code that both attempt to modify an account record. The first makes the account "inactive" if it is in a "pending" status, as a scheduled job, and the second is a trigger on a child record that updates the account status to "active" when the record is set to a certain status. For this example, the lookup field from the child object to the account is a lookup, so there is no implicit locking on the account. The developer doesn't use FOR UPDATE.
The developer tests both of these code units, and everything seems to work just fine, so they deploy this code to production. However, they've created a race condition. If the trigger runs at almost the exact same time as the scheduled job (within milliseconds), it is possible that the account's status gets updated to "active" from the trigger, but the scheduled job marks the account as "inactive" just milliseconds later. The business logic has failed to set the status to "active."
Adding the FOR UPDATE keyword in both places fixes this problem. In our example, the trigger runs first, and changes the status from "pending" to "active." The scheduled job, also using FOR UPDATE, experiences a brief pause for the trigger to finish executing, and the query within the scheduled job no longer queries the account that just became "active," since the lock waited for the account to finish updating.
In the second scenario, imagine just the trigger that we had from the first scenario, but this time two users attempt to create two separate child records on the same account, and the developer had not used FOR UPDATE. Since we already have the Account ID, it makes sense to just update the record without worrying about a query, right?
As long as the trigger completes quickly, nothing bad happens. However, if the transactions take longer than a few hundred milliseconds, because DML locks fail faster than FOR UPDATE, one of the users will get a UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW error. If the developer had used FOR UPDATE, both transactions would have completed successfully.
In small orgs, it is usually okay to ignore FOR UPDATE. Problems like those described above would be vanishingly rare. However, in a larger org with many records, many users, and frequent transactions, not using FOR UPDATE will cause random errors for users and/or integrations. As a defense against these errors, developers should always explicitly lock any records they are about to modify or even those that might cause extended lock durations for (e.g. while updating a child record).
Basically, by not using FOR UPDATE, you are taking a chance that records will be incorrectly updated, or users will experience row locking errors. The chances of this happening are miniscule in orgs with low traffic, but increase significantly as the org gets larger and has more users. Even if you don't modify the records you're querying, keep in mind that your queries can return stale data without FOR UPDATE.
Developers should always at least consider using FOR UPDATE. If you don't lock your rows, you introduce the risk of querying old data, overwriting near-concurrent updates, and/or avoidable UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors. Records that are updated fairly frequently should use row locks.
On the other hand, using FOR UPDATE does increase database contention, so it's useful to not use row locks for data that doesn't change frequently, such as Custom Settings, Custom Metadata, Products, and so on. Using row locks on records that only change infrequently will likely increase transaction times, perhaps to unacceptably high limits, for records that are used frequently but updated infrequently.

Thanks @sfdcfox for the great explanation. It was helpful.
